# link button not showing as a link

Tags: asp.net, asplinkbutton

link btn not displaying as it should

```
<th style="width:200px;">
              <asp:LinkButton id="linkBtn" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' OnCommand="LoadCheckListRecordEntry"/>
       </th>
```

The data inside the 'Text' doesnt appear as a link btn should, its just in normal text, if the user clicks on it however it will perform what it is meant to...but for visual representation it does not show the different btn it and the next row??

---

EDIT:

```
<asp:Repeater id="rptChecklistRecords" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table class="detailstable FadeOutOnEdit">
            <tr>   
              <th style="width:200px;">Title</th> 
              <th style="width:200px;">Timestamp</th>    
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
             <tr>                  
               <th style="width:200px;">

                              <asp:LinkButton id="linkBtn" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' OnCommand="LoadCheckListRecordEntry"/>

               </th>  
               <th style="width:200px;"><%# Eval("Timestamp") %></th>  
             </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Do you have any stylesheets that could cause this?

Comment: im only using the page to display a repeater: please see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a CSS class to it and style that

```
 <asp:LinkButton CssClass="linkBtn" id="linkBtn" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' OnCommand="LoadCheckListRecordEntry"/>
```

CSS

```
 a.linkBtn {
      text-decoration: underline; 
      color: blue
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a CSS style that is changing the appearance of your link. Check with F12 tools or similar to see what style(s) are being applied to the tag.

```
<th style="width:200px;">
              <asp:LinkButton id="linkBtn" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' 
OnCommand="LoadCheckListRecordEntry"/>
       </th>
```

Comment: thanks for reply iv tried to add in css:
.LinkBtn
{
    color:Highlight;
}

Comment: then ....<span class ="LinkBtn">
                              <asp:LinkButton id="linkBtn" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' OnCommand="LoadCheckListRecordEntry"/>
                    </span>
but still no joy

Answer (score 1):

on the webpage "linkbutton" renders as anchor("<a/>") tag
hence it will not show as link until you specify a href to it
or style it with the css to look like a link

Answer (score 0):

Use CCS for background image, use &nbsp as Link text and use Response.Redirect(YourPage) on Click event

Enjoy ;)

Comment: This question has answer already.Please check question before answer it.